# Calculating the probability density function of the sum of two independent random variables that have $\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ as a density function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, convolution

> Suppose you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, both independent
>   and which follow the Laplace distribution with $x\mapsto
> > \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ as density function. Calculate the density
>   function of $X+Y$

We know that if $X,Y$ are both random variables that are independent, then the density of $X+Y$ is the convolution of density functions of $X$ and $Y$.

So I get then  if $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$ as the density function of $X,Y$, then $(f\star f)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x-y)f(y) dy$

My approach to calculate $f \star f$ was to first handle the case when $x \geq 0$. We thus have:

$$(f \star f)(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|x-y|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|y|}dy $$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}|y|}dy + \int_{x}^{+ \infty}e^{\frac{1}{2}(y-x)}e^{-\frac{1}{2} y}dy  $$
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)}e^{\frac{1}{2}y}dy+\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y} dy +  \int_{x}^{+ \infty}e^{\frac{1}{2}(y-x)}e^{-\frac{1}{2} y}dy $$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x + y}dy + \int_{0}^xe^{-\frac{1}{2}x}dy + \int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-y -\frac{1}{2}x}dy = e^{\frac{1}{2}x} + e^{\frac{-1}{2}x} - e^{-\frac{3}{2}} $$
Is my approach so far correct?

Comment: Section 2.3 of *The Laplace Distribution and Generalizations* (2001) by Kotz et al. shows in detail the computations that result in 
$$
f_{X+Y}(x) = \frac14\left(1+|x| \right)e^{-|x|}.
$$

Comment: Distribution of $X+Y$ would be the same as that of $X-Y$ by symmetry. The derivation of the latter is shown [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100746/difference-between-two-i-i-d-laplace-distributions?) on CV.  Maybe this will help to do the integration correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** The Comment by @Math1000 seems correct. The density function in the comment is a good fit to the histogram of a million sums $S = X + Y$ of standard Laplace random variables. I simulated a Laplace random variable as a difference of two
standard exponential random variables. (I wonder if the distribution of $S$
is more easily obtained as the difference to two gamma random variables [sums of exponentials].)

```
x1 = rexp(10^6);  x2 = rexp(10^6);  x = x1-x2
y1 = rexp(10^6);  y2 = rexp(10^6);  y = y1-y2
s = x + y
hist(s, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.25))
curve(.25*(1+abs(x))*exp(-abs(x)), add=T, col="red", n=10001)
```

[image]